# ui-bootstrap pagination items-per-page not changing page size

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I hate asking this question, because it seems like all pagination questions have been answered.  However, I do not follow what is making the pagination pages shorten.  I believe that my example is very similar to other examples.

I am getting the correct number of tabs, current page is changing correctly as well.  However, the length is not matching the assigned items-per-page limit.

Here is my controller

```
viewsModule.controller('CountryCtrl', ['$scope', 'cacCountries', function($scope, cacCountries) {

$scope.loading = true;
$scope.countries = [];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 20;
$scope.maxSize = 20;

cacCountries().then(function(countries) {
    // console.log(countries);
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.countries = countries;
    $scope.totalItems = countries.length;

});
```

}]);

I have set my itemsPerPage to 20

In my html I made sure to reference the itemsPerPage

```
<pagination  
        total-items="totalItems" 
        items-per-page= "itemsPerPage"
        ng-model="currentPage" 
        class="pagination-sm">
</pagination>
```

I am getting back 13 tabs for 250 objects in the array.  However, all 250 objects are showing up.  I am expecting 20 per page.

The ng-repeat is plain

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries |filter:search ">
```

What could I be missing that would bind current page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pagination directive gives you a way to present to the user the list of selectable pages based on the size of the data and other parameters, and lets the user easily control the current page.

It does not actually filter the data for you. You still have to apply the `itemsPerPage`, `currentPage` etc within your `ng-repeat`.

One way to do this is to add an additional filter to help with skipping

```
app.filter('offset', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        return input.slice(start);
    };
})
```

and then use this with limitTo to control the paging

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:search | offset: (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo:itemsPerPage"> 
    {{country.name}}
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/gr2uksvu/)

Answer (score -1):

Old question.. but it worth to answer with the simple method.

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries.slice((currentPage -1) * itemsPerPage, currentPage * itemsPerPage) ">
```

[Fork JSFiddle from @sheilak](http://jsfiddle.net/fr2owktx/1/)